# What is it all about this usage? would of+verb

Tags: grammar, error

> We short men are in big trouble because if we want a shoe that feels decent we feel short and you can’t put in lifts, if you get a shoe with lifts it doesn’t feel comfortable I feel really trapped, that why I cannot believe that there is a god because if there was he **wouldn’t of don’t** this to me and made me only 5.4″ he or it **would of made** me to be at lease the regular American height which is 5.8” or taller , its a disaster to be short for a male.

The text is written by a native English speaker. It is the first time I face a usage in which *would of + verb* is used. Is it grammatically correct? What is the meaning of the parts I have shown in bold?

Comment: *Of* here, in both instances, is a nonstandard spelling of *have*, reflecting the actual pronunciation. *Don't* is a clear mistake for *done*. There are other mistakes in this passage, too. Do not emulate these usages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage `verb of verb` (like `would of made`) is bad. Native English speakers often use it because they learned from hearing English spoken, but not from studying its structure. For instance, take this sentence:

> Last night, I could've studied, but I played games.

Here, the speaker uses `could've` as a short form of `could have`, making the full verb phrase `could have studied`. However, when listening to this said, it sounds just like `could of studied`. If you didn't study the structure of English, you might not know that's incorrect grammar, and think `could've` is actually `could of`. Because of this, some people actually write and type `verb of verb` instead of `verb've verb`.

You should never use `verb of verb`.

Answer (score 7):

This sentence/paragraph is very poorly written and contains a number of grammar, punctuation, word, and spelling errors.   Although the writer might (claim to) be a native English speaker, they have done a very bad job in this example.

The two bold phrases are confusing to you because they are incorrect:

- *"...he **wouldn't of don't** this..."  should be "he **wouldn't *have done*** this..."
- *"...it **would of made** me..." should be "...it **would *have* made** me..."

As StoneyB pointed out: Do not emulate these usages.