# The sound effects could of been better

Tags: spelling

"The sound effects could of been better."

I found the above comment on YouTube.
The correct sentence is of course:

"The sound effects could have been better"
or
"The sound effects could've been better."

I wonder if he(or she) deliberately wrote "of" instead of "have."
I ask this because I often see this type of misspelling.

Comment: Yeah, s/he "could of." Why don't you leave a comment asking her/him? Or did you already do that? Anyway, we can't read the person's mind. And since you know the difference netween the two spellings, what more can be said? Also, please provide a LINK to where you found the comment.

Comment: Duplicates to the spelling question include: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53105/what-is-it-all-about-this-usage-would-ofverb and http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/87016/of-being-used-instead-of-have

Comment: See [**this link.**](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/couldof.html)

Answer (score 2):

As many sites on the English language explain, "could of" (could've) is commonly written for "could have" - along with "should of" (should've), "might of" (might've) and their cousins.

The error arises from the manner in which people speak and is most common among people more familiar with the spoken rather than the written form of English.

It arises because "could've" sounds so close to "could of". Of course, it's wrong.

See:

[www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/could-of-or-could-have](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/could-of-or-could-have)

[englishplus.com/grammar/00000204.htm](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000204.htm)

...and many others