# Would of or would have?

Tags: word-usage

I‘ve read a few shortstories online and I kept seeing the sentence:“what would of happend…“
So I‘m not sure if it’s correct or it should be „would have“, since english isn’t my first language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is it all about this usage? would of+verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53105/what-is-it-all-about-this-usage-would-ofverb)

Or this question on EL&U: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/493269/how-come-people-say-would-of

Comment: "Would of" is not correct. It's an error. The error happens because the contraction "would've" sounds like "would of". To be blunt, it's indicative of the writer having a substandard level of education.

Comment: @BillyKerr - agreed. An error. However, I retired last year from a government office in Bristol, UK, where most of the staff were local (I was born elsewhere). Quite a number of them not only wrote 'would of', 'could of', should of', 'might of', etc, but also audibly and clearly said it as well! These were white-collar people in administrative roles, and one was a manager. One might have hoped that their education was adequate, at least. I did wonder if I should consider it a dialect form. Some even said e.g. 'if I had of known' instead if 'if I had known'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - hmm . . . not sure it's dialect specific TBH. The examples I've seen are plastered all over the web/facebook/twitter, etc.  Americans are just as guilty of it as we Brits are.